# MySql Turkish Characters

Tags: mysql, character-encoding, turkish

I'm writing a program. This program transfers data to MySql database which is in SQL Server Datas.
MySql database default charset is Latin1. Latin5 charset is usually used for Turkish characters. But I can't change mysql table's charset because it's a very old database.
Is there any way to import turkish chars to mysql database correctly?

Comment: You might be interested in following the proposals for potential new SE sites including [Turkish Language & Usage](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/30873/turkish-language-usage?referrer=wKPqNxBBY-xKcrw-ScJbLA2) and [StackOverflow in Turkish](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/34945/stack-overflow-in-turkish?referrer=6DTBHmak2NY7uyvjVsZajA2).

Answer (score 1):

To test try:

```
CREATE TABLE newtable LIKE oldtable;

-- change the character latin character set to latin5
ALTER TABLE newtable MODIFY latin1_text_col TEXT CHARACTER SET latin5;

INSERT INTO newtable
SELECT * from oldtable;
```

If everything looks good you can drop the old table and rename the newtable to have the same name as the oldtable.

Comment: I haven't  to create a new a table. I must insert datas to old table.

Comment: does latin 5 include english characters like w or q ?